# フォルダ内にある2つ違う形式のファイルのうち、片方の作成日が一番古いファイルを削除

Tags: powershell

スクリプト開発初心者です。

同じフォルダ内に、pngファイルと、txtファイルがいくつかあり、
作成日が一番古いtxtファイルだけを削除する処理を実装したく、
下記のコードを参考に考えているのですが、
作成日が一番古いファイルの抽出方法が思いつきません。
何か良い方法、もしくは、このコマンドを使った方が良いなど
ありましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

回答、お願い致します。

```
$files = Get-ChildItem <対象フォルダのパス> | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime
$files = $files[1 .. $files.length]
foreach($file in $files)
{
    Remove-Item $file
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Select-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/hh849895.aspx)を使うことでしょうか。`-First`または`-Last`で指定個数を取得できます。

```
Get-ChildItem "対象フォルダのパス" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1 | Remove-Item
```

尚、`LastWriteTime`は更新日であり`CreationTime`が作成日になります。